# Spring boot views not working

Tags: spring-boot

This is my first Spring Boot example and on the first step. I created a SpringBoot project in STS 3.8 like this:

File -> New Spring Starter Project
Dependecies -> Web

I created the following controller in src/main/java/com.first.boot

**IndexController**
    package com.first.boot;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index(){
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Next, I created view index.html in src/main/resources/templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  Welcome to your first Spring Boot Page
</body>
</html>
```

Then I run the project as:
Right click on project -> Run as -> Spring Boot App

The console shows proper mappings and Tomcat startup information

```
Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.first.boot.IndexController.index()

Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)

Started FirstSpringBootApplication in 4.096 seconds (JVM running for 4.843)

Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started

FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 64 ms
```

But whenever I run localhost:8080 on browser, I see this page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 13 08:22:13 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

There are no errors in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding following dependency solved the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```